# React Native, TypeScript - Property 'includes', 'finds' does not exist on type 'any[]' no matter what configuration is setup

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have found this question asked in many many many places but not a single one of the answers has worked for me. My hunch is that it has something to do with me working in react-native but I am uncertain.

Basically I can't use es7 Array properties like `find` or `includes` without my linter claiming there is an error. There isn't one (the react-native Javascript environment includes this properties) but no matter what I do I can't remove the error.

The bulk of responses to this issue center around altering `tsconfig.json`, specifically the `lib` or `target` properties.

My current `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es2016.array.include"],
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "strict": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  }
}
```

Based on the documentation `es2016.array.include` is a valid value for the lib property but I still see the error `Property includes does not exist on type any[]`.

I have tried setting target to es2015, es2016, es2017, es2018, es5, es6, and esnext. I have tried adding various things to my lib param including es6, es6, es7, dom, es2016, es2017, es2018, esnext, and the specific properties like es2106.array.includes but none of these values or any combination remove this error from my linter.

Comment: So the code executes but the linter complains? Which version of ```tsc```?

Comment: Where do you see the error, during transpilation or during execution? The `tsconfig.json` change is only supposed to act during transpilation. It doesn't add polyfills for the function, which will _not_ exist on React Native executables (since they tend to use an old version of JavaScriptCore on Android). In that case you'd need to add them through core-js or other polyfills. React Native is supposed to come with those through babel, but I wonder how complete it is.

Comment: okay I am new to typescript so I did not realize that. This error is only being shown via tslint in VSCode. When I compile it isn't present, so I guess I'm barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: also fwiw `Array.includes` and `Array.find` are polyfilled in all react-native javascript runtimes: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment

Answer (score 0):

it helps me

In tsconfig.json
"lib": ["es6", "ES2016.Array.Include"],